# Does Raspberry Pi Zero have a polyfuse?

Tags: power, pi-zero

The question says it all. If you have a definite answer, it would be great if you could post a photo of the pi zero, where the fuse is pointed out.

Comment: Questions are not for answers

Comment: OK, should I create a new answer from it, and remove the answer? I am not sure.

Comment: It is entierly valid to answer your own question. It would be even better to edit the current answer, since you got the info there, but you might be a tad low on reputation.

Comment: OK; I just moved it into the answer part. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: This looks much better and readable. Nice job

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Pi Zero does not have a fuse (polyfuse or otherwise).

See this Raspberry Pi org forum [post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=850752#p850752).

Also see these limited [schematics](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/RPI-ZERO-V1_3_reduced.pdf).

Answer (score 9):

**NO polyfuse for raspberry pi zero**

Thanks to Joan I got the information to complete this request.
Here are the schematics for the power supply of both raspberry pi Zero and PRI 3, .

Raspberry Pi Zero without fuse:

[image]

And Here for comparision RPI3 with polyfuse:

[image]

Comment: So: on the bright side the RPi Zero is not going to suffer from volt-drop to the same extent when power is drawn from the +5V pins on the GPIO connections...!

Answer (score 3):

It does not have a polyfuse, but good fuses are cheap. If you want a fuse, use a nice glass fuse:
[image: fuse1]

Or a tiny fuse:
[image: fuse2]

To check if you've popped it, just use an ohm measurement. You also do not have to waste a day or more praying that your polyfuse has saved you.

Or add your own polyfuse:
[image: fuse3]

Comment: Of course you will have to use the _right_ fuse (for a fuse of current rating Iₙ you will need to draw at least 2 * Iₙ and possibly more to get it to fuse in a _reasonable_ time) and as far as semiconductor equipment with a glass/ceramic fuse you can often find that the circuit will work fine without any of that nasty _volt-drop_ associated with _poly-fuses_ - it is just that in the event of an over-voltage or down-stream overload the semiconductors protect the fuse by burning out in an _open-circuit_ manner so as to not cause the fuse to blow... 8-P

Comment: @SlySven Yes, a fast fuse. The right fuse. I like glass-case fuses in proper fuse mountings. Polyfuses are silly.